Optional type annotation string in SQLModel
I'm working on a FastAPI/SQLModel project and, since we've deprecated Python 3.9, I'm replacing each Optional[X] with X | None.
I have a problem with Type annotation strings.
For example, take this class
from typing import Optional

class OAuthAccount(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "oauthaccount"
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    user: Optional["User"] = Relationship(back_populates="oauth_accounts")

If I replace the last type hint with "User" | None I get this error
E   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'NoneType'

Is there any way to solve this, or am I stuck with Optional?
Thanks

Wrap the entire thing with quotes, not just User: 'User | None'. There should be a dupe somewhere.

Duplicate: Python 3.10+: Optional[Type] or Type | None (not a very good one, but oh well). Specifically, this currently-negative-vote answer.

Assuming User is defined somewhere else, just write User | None without quotes:
user: User | None = Relationship(back_populates="oauth_accounts")


this is what I have done in all other cases, but in this specific case it is necessary to refer to the User class by string: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/relationship-attributes/type-annotation-strings/
